# smtplib bug? starttls/quit fails when called the second time

Tags: python, python-2.7

Take this code

```
import smtplib
s = smtplib.SMTP()
s.set_debuglevel(1)

print "-------------------------------------------------------------------------"
s.connect("smtp.gmail.com",587)
s.starttls()
s.login("USERNAME","PASSWORD")
s.quit()

print "========================================================================="

s.connect("smtp.gmail.com",587)
s.starttls()
s.login("USERNAME","PASSWORD")
s.quit()
print "-------------------------------------------------------------------------"
```

first time it connects, it starts just fine....
second time it produces an exception about TLS as seen here...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mtest.py", line 12, in <module>
    s.starttls()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 635, in starttls
    raise SMTPException("STARTTLS extension not supported by server.")
smtplib.SMTPException: STARTTLS extension not supported by server.
```

Am I missing something stupid or is there a bug?

P.s. I wrote this test as I was getting the same problem in my other 'threaded' script, so wanted to make sure that it was nothing to do with threading.

Comment: add s.ehlo() before s.starttls(), then the server will tell you that it supports tls, then you can starttls.

Comment: adding the s.ehlo() worked a treat. DUUHH :-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that after the `s.quit()` the connection `s` is dead and cannot be used for anything else. If so, you'd need another `s = smtplib.SMTP()` for the second mail transfer.

The [quit() documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.quit) seems to suggest this is so:

> Terminate the SMTP session and close the connection.